# JQuery selector that uses a "data" attribute

Tags: jquery

I have problem with JQuery selector that uses a "data" attribute.
I need to get a div that has a specific class and has a specific data attribute.
This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container" name="templates-list" id="templates-list" style="width: 700px;">
    <div class="panel panel-default tmpl-select-panel" data-index="0" style="width: 700px;" title="Partite totali giocate da ogni squadra: 6">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel panel-default tmpl-select-phase-panel pull-left" style="width: 170px; margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:0px">
                <div class="panel-heading">Fase 1</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Squadre: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">12</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Gironi: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">2</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Sq./girone: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">6</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Partite/sq.: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">5</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default tmpl-select-phase-panel pull-left" style="width: 100px; margin-right:-20px; margin-bottom:0px">
                <div class="panel-heading">Fase Finale</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Squadre: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">2</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Partite/sq.: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">1</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default tmpl-select-panel" data-index="1" style="width: 700px;" title="Partite totali giocate da ogni squadra: 4">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel panel-default tmpl-select-phase-panel pull-left" style="width: 170px; margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:0px">
                <div class="panel-heading">Fase 1</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Squadre: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">12</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Gironi: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">4</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Sq./girone: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">3</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Partite/sq.: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">2</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default tmpl-select-phase-panel pull-left" style="width: 100px; margin-right:-20px; margin-bottom:0px">
                <div class="panel-heading">Fase Finale</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Squadre: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">4</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 tmpl-select-label">Partite/sq.: </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 tmpl-select-value">2</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my JQuery code:

```
$('#templates-list').find(".tmpl-select-panel[data-index='1']")
```

This code does not return any objects.

Where I wrong?

**UPDATE**

In the same page I have other JQuery code like this;

```
$('#templates-list').on('mouseenter', '.tmpl-select-panel', function(event) {
            $(this).find('.tmpl-select-phase-panel').removeClass('panel-default');
            $(this).find('.tmpl-select-phase-panel').addClass('panel-primary');
        });
```

that works fine.

**RESOLVED**

The div elements contained in the master div "#templates-list" are dynamically created after a POST request.
At the moment that I try to select one of these elements, the elements are not created yet.

Comment: You don't have `data-index='2'` in your html

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake in the copy and paste the code.

It does not work even if I use data-index='1'.

Comment: Are you sure that you are referencing jQuery properly? And wrapping your actual jQuery call within a "document-ready" block?

Comment: Yes, I do many other thinks in the code.

For example, this code works:

    `$('#templates-list').on('mouseenter', '.tmpl-select-panel', function(event) {
                $(this).find('.tmpl-select-phase-panel').removeClass('panel-default');
                $(this).find('.tmpl-select-phase-panel').addClass('panel-primary');
            });`

Comment: Try placing a `debugger` statement prior to your specific line that targets these elements being called and open the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser to try and see what `$('#templates-list').find(".tmpl-select-panel[data-index='1']")` is targeting at that point. I can't see anything that would cause this to not work with the code you have provided.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector should be just fine, it's just that you don't current have an element within the markup that you provided that matches it (i.e. there is not an element with a `data-index="2"` attribute.

You'll notice if you use `data-index="0"` or `data-index="1"`, you'll see that the selector works just as expected as :

```
 <!-- Your Example Markup Here -->

<!-- Place your jQuery reference here -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){
    $('#templates-list').find("div.tmpl-select-panel[data-index='0']").css('color','red');
    $('#templates-list').find("div.tmpl-select-panel[data-index='1']").css('color','blue');
 });
</script>
```

would yield :

[image]

You can [see a working example of this here](http://jsbin.com/tiyece/edit?html,output).

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake in the copy and paste the code.
It does not work even if I use data-index='1'.

Answer (score 0):

> try this out. working  fine to me..

```
 $('#templates-list').find("div.tmpl-select-panel[data-index='0']"); //its working fine.
```

What I can see is there is no `div` element which have a attribute like `data-index='2'`.
So I have just tried `data-index='0'`. and its working fine to me

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake in the copy and paste the code.
It does not work even if I use data-index='1'.

Comment: @vittochan No matter. champ makes mistakes. Thanks.